# How many solutions does a equation have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Let's say we have an equation $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=30$
where $−1 \leq x_{1}, 2 \leq x_{2}, −3 \leq x_{3} \leq 3$

How many integer combinations are possible?

It would be easy without the $x_{3}$ condition locked from **both** sides.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hint : Use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @PhilJones how? I can't find anything where someone uses this theorem on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just solve it for a few of the $x_3$ values and find the pattern.  Let us define $y_1=x_1+1, y_2=x_2-2$ so our equation now becomes $y_1+y_2+x_3=29$ and $y_1,y_2 \ge 0$.  Then if $x_3=3$ we have $27$ solutions, if $x_3=2$ we have $28$ solutions and we want $27+28+\ldots 33$.  The symmetry makes this easy to sum to $7 \cdot 30=210$

Comment: Thanks! And another question, what if we continue and make the equation: $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=30$ with conditions: $−1 \leq x_{1}, 2 \leq x_{2}, −3 \leq x_{3} \leq 3, 4 \leq x_{4}, −5 \leq x_{5} \leq 5 $. How is this solvable?

Comment: @AStudent How do you think it would be solvable? How would you extend Ross's solution to the new problem?